# Having a Secure / Copy Protected DESKTOP Environment in Cent OS Linux

Tags: centos, gnome, desktop, vnc, nomachine

We have a VPS / Bare-metal server rented on a data-center and we access them over internet through user ID and password. That is direct access and there's no VPN in between. We access GNOME desktop environment directly through VNC client/Nomachine client. The VPS has VNC-server and NX-server running.

We want to have a secure environment for outsiders to work so that -

a) Nobody can copy code from inside desktop environment (vim or other editor) to outside client machine.

b) There's no internet access from insider VPS, so that a code can't be copied over to internet.

c) SSH is disabled (This is achieved) Of course for root/su users, the SSH and internet access is open.

Is there a way we can achieve this with VNC and IPTABLES etc. Plz note the direct inbound VNC access over internet to be intact. We don't own/rent any other machine on same LAN through which we can route traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative : A VNC client connected to the VPS cannot prevent
the remote client from taking a screenshot of his screen.
There is no such thing.

Your only defense would be to ensure that no sensitive information is visible
to insecure outsiders, with a desktop that does not contain any information
that you prefer to keep secret.

As it is, your question is much too general.
I suggest to break it into several parts for handling each detail that you want hidden.
You would also need to supply much more information about your environment
and how you will grant access to these accounts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here is little more detail (that I think may give a clearer picture) - 

1) OS - CentOS 8.1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here is little more detail (that I think may give a clearer picture) - 

1) OS - CentOS 8.1

2) Desktop - GNOME

3) Remote desktop sharing application - VNCSERVER and NXSERVER running on it from boot. SSH is blocked.

4) Client Machine - Normally an Windows laptop/PC.

5) Client software - VNCViewer / NOMachine CLient.

6) Type of application run inside VPS - mostly terminal and Vim from which code can be copied to clipboard.
    Also normal internet access through which code can be taken away (like attach in email or git clone to a depot in net).

Comment: The idea is to block here direct code copy from a text editor or bulk transfer through net.

HOwever as long as somebody is working on a shared screen they can still screen capture run OCR or at least take it through a mobile phone etc device and run image to text.

The point is making things difficult than having 1K/10K/100K/1M lines of code copied just like that.

Comment: For NOMachine you can disable file transfers in *Show the server status > Server preferences > Transfer*. More info in [this article](https://www.nomachine.com/DT10O00151&dn=disable%20disk). For VNCViewer this depends on the product. For Linux, you may assign user groups and tighten up permissions of key folders, perhaps using [ACLs](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-acls-on-linux). You ,ay also do [Traffic management](https://documentation.online.net/en/dedicated-server/tutorials/network/configure-wondershaper) to limit bandwidth, although this is on the entire interface.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at the articles.

Yes - we do create smaller groups and each person works in silos. However as we move forward, more of common build infra or library has to be in one place to speed up things.

Hence the problem statement..